# Is chkdsk with the /scan option enough to check for logical and physical errors and bad sectors?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, chkdsk

I checked an external HD connected to Windows Server 2012 R2 with the following command and output (sorry it is in Portuguese - it says there are no problems in the file system and no action is necessary, and no other text says anything significant):

```
E:\>chkdsk e: /scan
O tipo do sistema de arquivos é NTFS.
O rótulo do volume é Seagate Expansion Drive.

Estágio 1: examinando a estrutura básica do sistema de arquivos...


  347392 de registros de arquivos processados.
Verificação de arquivos concluída.


  0 registros de arquivos grandes processados.


  0 registros de arquivos inválidos processados.

Estágio 2: examinando a ligação do nome do arquivo...


  413056 de entradas de índice processadas.
Verificação de índices concluída.


  0 arquivos não indexados verificados.


  0 arquivos não indexados recuperados.

Estágio 3: examinando os descritores de segurança...
Verificação de descritores de segurança concluída.


  32832 arquivos de dados processados.

Não há problemas no sistema de arquivos.
Nenhuma ação necessária.

 976759807 KB de espaço total em disco.
 682677304 KB em 314448 arquivos.
    142432 KB em 32834 índices.
         0 KB em setores defeituosos.
    443199 KB em uso pelo sistema.
     65536 KB ocupados pelo arquivo de log.
 293496872 KB disponíveis em disco.

      4096 bytes em cada unidade de alocação.
Total de  244189951 unidades de alocação no disco.
  73374218 unidades de alocação disponíveis em disco.
```

I'm not sure about chkdsk's parameters. Is using /scan enough to check for logical and physical errors and bad sectors? Is the external HD expected to be fine?

Comment: Seagate has more advanced tools for their hardware.  Seatools will do a more advanced test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disk seems to be healthy. You can always run "chkdsk /f" to fix the problems with NTFS.

If you are looking for a deeper hard drive scan, I would suggest Victoria: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/Victoria.shtml